# PHP - Same values display on both different textboxes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, I have made a code to edit radio buttons, drop down lists and text boxes.

The Division->(dropdown list and Other: textbox) and External->(textbox) are under the same "client_details".

[This is the example of the edit form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2R8m.png)

This is the code I made.

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Edit a Contract </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    ID: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE `id` = $id";
            $result = $con->query($sql);
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $client_type = $row['client_type'];
        ?>

    <label for = "client1">
    <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client1" value="Division" <?php echo ($client_type == 'Division')? "checked" : "" ?> onclick="toggleDivision()"/> Division
    </label>
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
    <label for ="client2">
    <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client2" value="External" <?php echo ($client_type == 'External')? "checked" : "" ?> onclick="toggleExternal()"/> External
    </label>
    &nbsp 
    <input type="text" id="extText" name="client_details2" value="<?php echo $row['client_details']; ?>" disabled /> 
    <br><br>

    <div id="division">
        Division:
        <select  id="mySelect" name="client_details" onclick="enableTextbox()" disabled>
            <option value="Choose" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Choose' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Choose Division...</option>
            <option value="Distribution" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Distribution' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Distribution</option>
            <option value="Transmission" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Transmission' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Transmission</option>
            <option value="Generation" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Generation' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Generation</option>
            <option value="Procument" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Procument' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Procument</option>
            <option value="Other" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Other' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Others</option>
        </select>   
        <br><br>
        Others:<input type="text" id="otherTxt" name="client_details1" value="<?php echo $row['client_details']; ?>"  disabled />
        <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>     

<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleExternal() {
    document.getElementById("extText").disabled = false;

    var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
    for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
        divis_el.children[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
function toggleDivision() {
    document.getElementById("extText").disabled = true;
    var val = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
    var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
    for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
        divis_el.children[i].disabled = false;
        divis_el.children[5].disabled = true;
    }
}

function enableTextbox() {
var val = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
if (val == 0 || val == 1 ||val == 2 ||val == 3 ||val == 4) { document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = true}
if (val == 5) { document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = false; }
}
</script>   

</body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$client_type = isset($_POST ['client_type']) ? $_POST['client_type'] :null;
$client_details = isset($_POST ['client_details']) ? $_POST['client_details'] :null;

if($client_type == 'Division'){
$client_details = isset($_POST ['client_details1']) ? $_POST['client_details1'] :null;
$client_details = isset($_POST ['client_details']) ? $_POST['client_details'] :null; // both variables under if statement are needed to successfully update the data avoiding blank values.
} else {
$client_details = isset($_POST ['client_details2']) ? $_POST['client_details2'] :null;
}

if($client_details == 'Other') {
    $client_details = isset($_POST ['client_details1']) ? $_POST['client_details1'] :null;
} 
$query = "UPDATE contracts set `client_type`=?, `client_details`=? WHERE `id`= ?";

$stmt = $con->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $client_type, $client_details, $id);
$stmt->execute();


if ($stmt->errno){
     echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
} else {
    echo "<br>Updated";
}

$stmt->close();
$con->close();                                 
}
?>
```

EDIT: What I meant is this.

As you can see the example picture from the link, the "Generation" values is displayed in all the textboxes under both Division and External after I updated the data because The value was taken from the drop down list.

The "Other" textbox is under division but it will only enabled to be entered after the selecting the value "Other" from the drop down list under Division.

I only wanted the the Division values displayed in the textbox only under Division and not the under External when Division radio button is chosen. And if I choose External and input data in the textbox, I only wanted the value displayed in the textbox under External only after updated.

When I select the values and not "Other" value, the value should not displayed in the text box under Division. When I select "Other" value, then the value should be displayed in 'Other' textbox but I don't want the value to also displayed in the text box under External.

The question I'm trying ask is how to make the textbox values display values separately. I don't want the same values displaying in all the dropdown list and textboxes? How do I do that? Sorry for poor explaination as English is my second language

Comment: I find it a bit unclear what you want, what's the `textbox`?

Comment: I edited with brief explaination. Go check it again :)

Comment: by textboxes, do you mean `input type="text"`?

Comment: yes. thats what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's no wonder why both are displaying the samething, their values are both just `<?php echo $row['client_details']; ?>`

You already have a checking variable, just not sure why you didn't use it here.

E.g.

```
<?php $extText = ($client_type == 'External') ? $row['client_details'] : "" ?>
<?php $divText = ($client_type == 'Division') ? $row['client_details'] : "" ?>
<input type="text" id="extText" name="client_details2" value="<?php echo extText; ?>" disabled /> 
Others:<input type="text" id="otherTxt" name="client_details1" value="<?php echo $divText; ?>"  disabled />
```